# How to add a new page to navigator stack each time the current tab changes in a TabBar flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and I am trying to clone instagram. I have checked online of how to implement the bottomNavigator and have it visible on every screen, and all of them pointed to me using the TabView and TabBar. It works fine, but when I change to a new tab, it is not getting added to the navigation stack. So, when I click on the mobile back button, it closes the application cause there are no items in stack to pop. Below is an example code of the tab navigator.

```
class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

How do I change this code so that every time I change the tab, it works the way it is right now, but the new tab should be pushed to the navigation stack. So that I can click on the device back button and it takes me back to tab1 and not close the application.

**I want the navigation to work and feel exactly like how instagram does on android.**

Answer (score 0):

**Basic BottomNavigationBar source:** [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

```
int _selectedIndex = 0;
static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
  Text(
    'Index 0: Home',
    style: optionStyle,
  ),
  Text(
     'Index 1: Business',
     style: optionStyle,
  ),
  Text(
     'Index 2: School',
     style: optionStyle,
  ),
];

void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      // This is where the content is changing and 
      // you can have it visible on every screen
      child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.business),
          title: Text('Business'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.school),
          title: Text('School'),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ),
  );
}
```

For the push and pop logic, instead of using list of _widgetOptions, you need to use `Navigator` and provide your own `onGenerateRoute`. You can learn about it here [Navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/Navigator.html). It will become something like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
    ),
    body: Navigator(
      key: ..,
      initialRoute: ..,
      onGenerateRoute: ..,
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.business),
          title: Text('Business'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.school),
          title: Text('School'),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      onTap: ..,
    ),
  );
```

It's kind of complex to explain it here so I just give you some references how to implement `onGenerateRoute`.

1. A wonderful package called [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route)
2. Make your own `onGenerateRoute` [clean-navigation-in-flutter-using-generated-routes](https://medium.com/flutter-community/clean-navigation-in-flutter-using-generated-routes-891bd6e000df)